# If there is a conductance quantum, why is the resistivity in a superconductor exactly zero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductance_quantum

From what I have read, this is the maximum conductance a perfect wire can have. Therefore, the inverse of this number should be the minimum resistance a perfect wire could have. So, why is then said that in the superconductor state of a material the resistivity is exactly zero?

Shouldn't it be, at least, the inverse of this conductance quantum?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If those 12.9 kΩ were the minimum resistance possible, how do you explain for example 100 Ω resistors?

Comment: *Note that the conductance quantum does not mean that the conductance of any system must be an integer multiple of $G_0$* - The wikipedia article you linked.